# Intersection of a quadratic and a plane is a quadratic?

Tags: geometry

Consider a quadratic equation in two variables, $f(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + d$. Let $P$ be a plane, so it is described by some equation $\alpha x + \beta y + \gamma z = \delta$ (where at least one of $\alpha, \beta$ or $\gamma$ is nonzero).

It appears, through some examples of $f$ and $P$ that I've graphed, that the intersection of the graph of $f$ with the plane $P$ is a curve that looks like the graph of an ordinary one-dimensional parabola or hyperbola or general quadratic equation in one variable.

For example, the graph of $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$ seems to intersect the plane $2x + y + 2z = 1$ in a hyperbola, and it seems to intersect $2x + y = 1$ in a parabola. (In fact it seems that any vertical cross-section will produce a parabola.)

Is there a proof or counterexample of this phenomenon?

(Another (optional) question: how does this all relate to conic sections?)

Comment: A counter example would be $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ intersected with the plane $z=1$, which is a circle. I think this phenomenon would be true in the case that $a$ and $c$ are opposite signs.

Comment: Are you sure you mean quadratic? Check out if you mean quadric.

Comment: This **is** [conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section): those intersections are always parabolas, hyperbolas, ellipses, or circles (although circles are usually just considered an ellipse that happens to have the same major and minor axis lengths).

Comment: The proof is easy: perform a rotation carrying the given plane parallel to the $xy$ plane. After the rotation the equation of the quadric is still quadratic and the equation of the plane is $z=k$: substituting gives then a quadratic equation in $x$, $y$ which is then the equation of a (possibly degenerate) conic section.